Why is FFmpeg -acodec ac3 not in sync as the original audio?
I am just trying to change the audio from AAC to AC3 and it creates a video where the audio is slightly out of sync. If I watch the original video then it is perfect.
I have read some posts where the describe this situation being similar to inserting a video that has one set of frames per second, into another with a different set of frames per second.
ffmpeg -i 08-22-24-Not-if-4K-PQ.mp4 -acodec ac3 not-if-ac3.mp4

Once more, the original file works as expected, but the new files which now has AC3 audio is out of sync.
AAC:

AC3:

In the other posts that I read, they were saying the difference in frame rate for audio does not matter, but something is obviously off.
How can I make sure that they audio is the same as the original, with the exception of being converted to AC3 encoding?

I received this answer from another post in case someone else is going through this issue:
ffmpeg -i 08-22-24-Not-if-4K-PQ.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a ac3 not-if-ac3.mp4

Other post, which lead me to finding this answer

Another post here on SuperUser? Please include a link to the other resource to help others and provide appropriate attribution.
